# If command does not exist, respond with various replies

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I would like to make this where if someone sends a command, if its not a command stored in ./cmds/ it kicks back a random response. The code below does not error out, it lets valid commands through but invalid commands get no response whatsoever. I shortened the code and took out a whole bunch of the responses and validCommands to be more efficient on here. I'm not sure whats causing the lack of response or what.

The closest I got to making this work was getting it to send a random response and the command response at the same time.
The code below is just the simplest version I have made so far.

```
let response = [
    'resp1',
    'resp2',
    'resp3'
]

let validCommands = [
    'cmd1',
    'cmd2',
    'cmd3'
];


if (!validCommands) {
    return message.channel.send(response[Math.floor(Math.random() * response.length)])
}
```

Comment: `if (!validCommands)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So Wuerfelfreak got me 90% there, kept having duplication issues because of how I added the code to the js file, the logics didn't work right. So I relocated it further up in the command and then every command gave a response from the let response section. then I relised the "validCommands" didn't allow for the prefix, so I sliced that. ended up with this which worked perfectly.

`if (!validCommands.includes(message.content.slice(prefix.length))) { return message.channel.send(response[Math.floor(Math.random() * response.length)])`

Answer (score 1):

Arrays in js are `truly`, meaning they convert to true if cast to boolean. Because `validCommands` is constant and always `true` your condition becomes `if (!true) {` and the response never executes.

I think it should be instead

```
if (! validCommands.includes(message.content)) { ... }
```